# Detecting whitespace in HTTP referer using Regex via htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, referer

I'm noticing some spoofed referers in my log files. I'm trying to match this with regex then redirect or block.

so far I have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ([ \t]) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* http://myurl.com [R=301,L]
```

to match

```
http://www.google.com/aclk?sa=L&ai=CQMQnRhqqU9ayMoGGpgO0qIGwBenqjYYF- (iPad; CPU OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X)fapm58BnLGFBQgAEAEgpobwF1DtwvevBGDJnu6LyKSsFMgBAaoEHk_Ql4Qm9ik5AliEnvP6NXHVLTEajDmGtvndNK_0RYAFs_j-GNgGBIAH-Y3hL5AHAw&sig=AOD64_3a7OrHry1krDs0QEW5MAsdgRg_Ng&rct=j&q=&ved=0CB8Q0Qw&adurl=http://noneya.com
```

Ive tested and it works here http://regex101.com/r/zN6iY7 but cant get it to trigger the rule using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

To be clear, I'm wanting to detect any whitespace inside of a referer url using regex via htaccess and redirect to another page if so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One reason it won't trigger is that the [test website](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) you're using doesn't have access to a whole bunch of variables... Such as `%{HTTP_REFERER}` It's not a great place to test elaborate rules.

Comment: actually I just tested it using %{HTTP_REFERER} with the modified htaccess and its triggering the rule and recognizing it but i appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've checked that the referer field contains spaces? Then this should be enough:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \s
RewriteRule ^ http://myurl.com [R=301,L]
```

Make sure it's in the `.htaccess` of your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

Comment: yes, some botting program checking my adwords ads. Pretty lame referer spoofing. Just want to block nosy bots with this.

Comment: Alright, then we're on the right track. Let me know if that rule is working for you. :)

Comment: actually that works perfectly. Now that being said, this isn't going to detect any trailing whitespace will it? Is that common to find in legit referer data?

Comment: Glad it works! It will find whitespace anywhere because the `\s` is not anchored (there's no `^`)